# How to get rid of null value while updating resource in one to many relationship in spring and hibernate

Tags: json, spring, hibernate, rest, api

I have two classes Category and Ads.Category has one to many relationship with ads ie,a category can have multiple ads.
I have used spring framework and hibernate as an ORM tool.
My category class is:

```
@Entity
public class Category {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int cid;
private String cname;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@JoinColumn(name = "cid")
List<Ad> ads;
//getter and setter,constructor
}
```

My ad class is:

```
@Entity
public class Ad {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int ad_id;
private String adName;
//getter and setter,constructor
}
```

My controller class for Category is:

```
@Controller
public class CategoryController {
@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;
Session session;

@Transactional
@RequestMapping(value = "category",method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String insertCategory(@RequestBody Category category) throws SQLException{
    session=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.save(category);
    return "succesful";
}

@Transactional
@RequestMapping(value = "updatecategory/{cid}",method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseBody
public String updateCategory(@RequestBody Category category,@PathVariable("cid") int cid) throws SQLException{
    Category category1=new Category();
    session=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    category1= (Category) session.get(Category.class,cid);
    category1.setAds(category.getAds());
    session.save(category1);
    return "succesful";
}
}
```

I am adding a new category like
localhost:8080/category

```
{"cname":"automobile"}
```

I insert an ad in this category like
localhost:8080/updatecategory/1

```
{"ads":[{"adName":"car"}]}
```

It works fine but when I add another ad in this same category ,the foreign key cid of the previous ad changes to null

localhost:8080/updatecategory/1

```
{"ads":[{"adName":"bike"}]}
```

Category table looks like

```
cat_id  cName
1       automobile
```

Ad table looks like:

```
ad_id  adName  c_id
1       car    <null>
2       bike    1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some time, I figured out the problem.
Replace your code with this. It worked for me.

```
@Transactional
@RequestMapping(value = "updatecategory/{cid}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseBody
public String updateCategory(@RequestBody Category category, @PathVariable("cid") int cid) throws SQLException {
    Category category1;
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    category1 = (Category) session.get(Category.class, cid);
    category1.getAds().addAll(category.getAds());
    if (category1 != null) {
        session.save(category1);
        return "successful";
    } else
        return "unsuccessful";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your code.

You are storing the `Session` object as an attribute of your controller despite the fact that the `Session` object is **not thread-safe**. Store it as a variable within your methods.

In your `updateCategory` method, you unnecessary create a new `Category` object and overwrite the variable immediately.

Your main problem here is that you are not setting the back reference for the `Ad` objects. You should explicitly call `Ad#setCategory` with the appropriate entity.

Comment: I am also interested in this question. Could you please explain the line "You should explicitly call Ad#setCategory with the appropriate entity" ?

Comment: If you have a relation like yours. When you have a `Category` and an `Ad`, you have to set up the relation like this: `Ad ad = new Ad(); Category c = ...; c.setAds(Collections.singleton(ad)); ad.setCategory(c);`

Answer (score 0):

In your code where the ID is set:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int cid;
```

Maybe you need to set a strategy for your cid.

Example:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int cid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code removes existing ads and replaces them with the new list of ads. So Hibernate sets the foreign key value to `null` in database for old ads.

To avoid that you need to add the new ads to the existing list of ads like this:

```
category1 = (Category) session.get(Category.class, cid);
category1.getAds().addAll(category.getAds());
session.save(category1);
```

And also, as said by galovics, the `session` is not `thread-safe`, so make it as method local variable instead of instance variable in your controller class.